# Ruby: how to perform "left join" on two arrays of hashes efficiently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, algorithm, hash

I am trying to left join the following arrays of hashes:

```
input:
a = [{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 2, name: 'Jack'}, {id: 3, name: 'Tom'}]
b = [{id: 3, age: 12}, {id: 2, age: 7}]
output:
[{id: 1, name: 'Bob', age: nil}, {id: 2, name: 'Jack', age: 7}, {id: 3, name: 'Tom', age: 12}]
```

Currently I am doing something along the lines with:

```
a.map do |x|
  {
   id:   x[:id], 
   name: x[:name], 
   age:  (b.detect{|y| x[:id] == y[:id]} || {age: nil}).fetch(:age)
  }
end
```

It works, but it is super slow when the data set is large.

Is there any better way to perform the "join" operation more efficiently?

Comment: Turn the left array of hashes into a hash of hashes keyed on the `:id` so you have `{1 => {id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, 2 => {id: 2, name: 'Jack'}, …}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're right. Fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = b.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:id]] = g[:age] }
  #=> {3=>12, 2=>7} 
a.map { |g| g.merge(age: h[g[:id]]) }
  #=> [{:id=>1, :name=>"Bob",  :age=>nil},
  #    {:id=>2, :name=>"Jack", :age=>7},
  #    {:id=>3, :name=>"Tom",  :age=>12}]
```

If `a` is to be modified in place, change the second line to

```
a.each { |g| g[:age] = h[g[:id]] }

a #=> [{:id=>1, :name=>"Bob",  :age=>nil},
  #    {:id=>2, :name=>"Jack", :age=>7},
  #    {:id=>3, :name=>"Tom",  :age=>12}]
```

Comment: This is definitely more rubyish than mine; since I luckily quit Ruby developing a couple of months ago, I seem to have 90% of vision lost :)

Comment: @mudasobwa, are you on to another language, changed your profession or retired from the workforce? Will delete this comment later.

Comment: I fell in love with [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org). I had been changing a profession once to copy-writing (besides university-time navvy and laborer experience,) and I am pretty sure I am with programming forever.

Comment: @mudasobwa I live in Cracow since 2011, in 2014 I've been to Jose's presentation where he was speaking about Elixir, at that moment I was at the very start of my programming career and did not understand much (pretty much nothing) of what he was saying, but the way he did it made me believe back than, that this language is the future. Cool that you've switched to it!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Yeah, José loves what he does and this is a main point why he does it great. Besides he is a brilliant software engineer.

Answer (score 4):

```
[a, b].map { |a| a.group_by { |e| e[:id] } }
      .reduce do |a, b|
          a.merge(b) { |_, v1, v2| v1.first.merge v2.first }
        end.values
      .map do |e|
         Array === e ? {age:nil, name:nil}.merge(e.first) : e
      end
```

The whole preparation step takes `O(N)` and the merge then is done as `O(N)`, plus the finalization takes `O(N)`.